# Update database in every two second

Tags: python, django, multithreading, cron, django-views

I am creating an app in django for update the database in every two second with values from stock exchange.  How can i update database using a python script from django. I am using urllib2 in script. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you are updating this data every 2 seconds, perhaps it would be better to store it in memory like Redis?

Answer (score 1):

You can quite easily have a python script that uses your models. This is what I do for example for a script that imports some external data to my database:

```
import os
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "<path>.settings")
```

Where you need to replace `<path>` by the name the module containing your settings. You can also copy this line from the script `manage.py`

One you have done it, you can import the models:

```
from <app>.models import *
```

For which you need to replace `<app>`. You can then create or update models, and call `save()` to update the database.

Finally, you can call this script by a cron, or better, let it run all the time, and sleep 2 seconds in a loop to update your database.